# Regarding Capturing Screen of Android Device and show on Desktop

Tags: android, sockets, vnc-server

I am developing an Android Application in which I have captured screeenshot.I am sending the image to Socket with Ip Address and Port No.I am able to connect to the ScreenBuffer.But the receiver that is Vnc Server is unable to receive the image.

So for reference as per my Findings I got the following samples

1) https://code.google.com/p/desktopsms/
2) https://code.google.com/p/remoteroid/

But I need to capture the screen of my Android Device on Desktop and Control My Device remotely
Based on My R & d I found that Real Vnc has apps that control the android device.But they require rooting which I dont need to do.

Has anyone worked on similar kind of issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi I haven't worked on creating any app similar to this, but I have worked on softwares like "android screencast" and "android commander".

Both were able to display my screen to PC.

But on rooting my Phone (froyo) I was even able to control it from PC with Android screencast. But I did the same for my other phone (Jelly Bean) it displayed the screen but I couldn't control.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ok.u mean to say .Without rooting I cannot implement the Screen Capture. Can you come to the chat room I created. I have some doubtshttp :                  chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55806/mobile-application

Comment: You could implement screen capture, but controlling with remote desktop require root permission.